# S3 access denied in Amplify Trips Planner Tutorial

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I just got to the very end of the tutorial on creating a Flutter Mobile App with an AWS Amplify back-end, but running the completed App (in an iOS simulator)

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-mobile-app-part-one/module-four/

I ran into an Exception:

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: StorageAccessDeniedException {
"message": "S3 access denied when making the API call.",
"recoverySuggestion": "HTTP error returned from service, review the underlyingException for details.",
"underlyingException": "Instance of 'UnknownSmithyHttpException'"
}
#0      StorageS3Service.headObject (package:amplify_storage_s3_dart/src/storage_s3_service/service/storage_s3_service_impl.dart:747:7)

#1      StorageS3Service.getProperties (package:amplify_storage_s3_dart/src/storage_s3_service/service/storage_s3_service_impl.dart:226:9)

#2      StorageS3Service.getUrl (package:amplify_storage_s3_dart/src/storage_s3_service/service/storage_s3_service_impl.dart:267:7)

#3      StorageService.getImageUrl (package:amplify_trips_planner/common/services/storage_service.dart:21:20)

#4      TripController.uploadFile (package:amplify_trips_planner/fe<…>

I also noticed (possibly related?) there's no way in the UI of the App to Log Out and Log In again?
Please advise